# karaf & jax-rs : The namespace attribute, 'http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs', of an element information item must be identical

Tags: jax-rs, karaf

I got some troubles making a jax-rs client with the version 4.0.8 of karaf. Everything is working on an older karaf (tested on a 4.0.3)

Any idea?

How to test/reproduce :

Just create a sample bundle with a blueprint.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
           xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs"
           xmlns:jaxrs-client="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs-client"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxrs.xsd
  http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.1.0.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs-client http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxrs-client.xsd
  ">


    <jaxrs-client:client id="testClient"
                  serviceClass="org.test..."
                  address="{url}">

    </jaxrs-client:client>
</blueprint>
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-import.3.1: The namespace attribute, 'xxx://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs', of an <import> element information item must be identical to the targetNamespace attribute, 'xxx://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs', of the imported document.

2017-06-26 14:58:40,024 | WARN  | nsole user karaf | NamespaceHandlerRegistryImpl     | 12 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.7.1 | NamespaceHandler org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.blueprint.JAXRSBPNam espaceHandler is behaving badly and should be fixed
2017-06-26 14:58:40,041 | WARN  | nsole user karaf | NamespaceHandlerRegistryImpl     | 12 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.7.1 | Unable to find namespace handler for ://cxf.apache.org/configuration/beans
2017-06-26 14:58:40,100 | WARN  | nsole user karaf | NamespaceHandlerRegistryImpl     | 12 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.7.1 | Unable to find namespace handler for ://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs
2017-06-26 14:58:40,123 | ERROR | nsole user karaf | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 12 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.7.1 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle /1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-import.3.1: The namespace attribute, '://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs', of an <import> element information item must be identical to the targetNamespace attribute, '://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs', of the imported document.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknow
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES-1540 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-7183, CXF Blueprint namespace don't work well with blueprint-core 1.7.x.

Try to update the cxf version that you are using. Try those versions 3.1.10, 3.0.13, 3.2.0 or above.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.11 for example</version>
</dependency>
```

Don't forget to check that the deployed version of CXF is also 3.1.10, 3.0.13, 3.2.0 or above. You can tap **feature:list | grep cxf** in your karaf command line.